# Using the Teamcity REST API to get a build Log

Tags: rest, teamcity

Say I have a specific build, such as:

https://example.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:161010

How would I get the build log of that build?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just download `http://your.teamcity.server/httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId=nnnn`.  Nice and easy.

This has now been added to the docs - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Log

Comment: thanks, could you be so kind as to link the reference? I did search the TC docs but didn't find anything.

Comment: I think it's documented in the "REST API" docs.  Alas, TeamCity makes it hard to find things.

Comment: Can't see it in the documentation today, but this definitely still works. Thanks! :)

Comment: In hindsight, I believe the URL format isn't documented.  I believe I found it by looking at the REST API output for builds, where TeamCity hands over quite a few URLs.

Comment: There is a ticket about the documentation problem here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-37177

Comment: Any chance of getting the build logs for the current running build using dotnet?